# How to pass Object using jsp:include param tag into another jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I am trying to send DTO Object from one jsp to another jsp using jsp:include tag. But it is always treating it as String. I can't able to use DTO in my included jsp file.

Here is a code ..

```
<c:forEach items="${attributeDTOList}" var="attribute" varStatus="status">  
         <jsp:include page="attributeSubFeatureRemove.jsp" >
             <jsp:param name="attribute" value="${attribute}" />
         </jsp:include>
</c:forEach>
```

attributeSubFeatureRemove.jsp file ..

```
<c:set value="${param.attribute}" var="attribute" />
<c:forEach items="${attribute.subFeatures}" var="subAttribute">
    <c:forEach items="${subAttribute.attributeValues}" var="subValue">
        <c:if test="${ subValue.preSelectionRequired}">
            <c:set var="replaceParams" value=":${subAttribute.name}:${subValue.name}" />
            <c:set var="removeURL" value="${fn:replace(removeURL, replaceParams, '')}" />
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach> 
    <jsp:include page="attributeSubFeatureRemove.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="subAttribute" value="${subAttribute}" />
    </jsp:include> 
</c:forEach>
```

Here I am trying to get attribute value from param, it is always sending String Type Value. Is there any way to send Object (DTO) in attributeSubFeatureRemove jsp file ? Please help.

Comment: @fiffy request.setAttribute wants variable. How i will define variable? It has to be set like this ${subAttribute}

Comment: No thats not working :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13510064/2885897

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think you really want tag files here.   That's way overkill and too confusing for what you want to accomplish.   You need to spend time understanding "scope".   Instead of tag files, I would:

1) Change your attribute to be in the "request" scope instead of the default "page" scope by changing this line:

```
<c:forEach items="${attributeDTOList}" var="attribute" varStatus="status">
```

to this

```
<c:forEach items="${attributeDTOList}" var="attribute" varStatus="status">
    <c:set var="attribute" value="${attribute}" scope="request"/>
```

That will make "attribute" a "requestScope" variable that can be used in other JSP files that are c:imported. (Note: forEach doesn't support scope attribute so use c:set to scope it inside each iteration.)

2) Change your original jsp:include to c:import.  So change it from:

```
<jsp:include page="attributeSubFeatureRemove.jsp" >
    <jsp:param name="attribute" value="${attribute}" />
</jsp:include>
```

to this

```
<c:import url="attributeSubFeatureRemove.jsp"/>
```

Note that we don't explicitly try to pass the attribute as a parameter, because we have already made it available to all c:imported pages in the "requestScope".

3) Modify your c:imported JSP to reference the attribute using the requestScope by changing this:

```
<c:set value="${param.attribute}" var="attribute" />
<c:forEach items="${attribute.subFeatures}" var="subAttribute">
```

to this

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.attribute.subFeatures}" var="subAttribute">
```

Here we no longer need the c:set because you already have the attribute available.   We just need to make sure we look in the requestScope for that variable, instead of in the default pageScope or as a parameter (because we are no longer passing it as a parameter).

This technique will be a lot easier for you to manage.

Comment: Scope attribute is undefined for <c:forEach> tag. Use <c:set> tag instead.
<c:set var="attribute" value="${attribute}" scope="request"></c:set>

Comment: Better you update your answer as suggest above in comment. Gr8 job.!!

Comment: The answer could use some clarity. It wasn't clear to me first that 1) 2) were steps. After following it did solve my problem though. I did not know jsp:param only passes Strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can not directly pass an Object using jsp:include param tag into another jsp.

However, you can pass that attribute's NAME (as a string) using jsp:include param tag into another jsp, Then in the included jsp, you can get that attribute itself by its name from requestScope.

in your main JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item" varStatus="status">  
     <jsp:include page="attributeSubFeatureRemove.jsp" >
         <jsp:param name="objName" value="item" />
     </jsp:include>
</c:forEach>
```

in attributeSubFeatureRemove.jsp:

```
object's name = ${param.objName}
object itself = ${requestScope[param.objName]}

Just for an easier access:
<c:set var="obj" value="${requestScope[param.objName]}" scope="page"></c:set>
obj=${obj}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I have solved the issue by using tag file. I am no longer using jsp:include tag now because it will always send String Type.

Here is a solution ..

```
<%@ taglib prefix="cms2" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/spine/surgery"%>
<c:forEach items="${attributeDTOList}" var="attribute" varStatus="status">  
     <cms2:attributeSubFeatureRemove attribute="${attribute}" /> 
</c:forEach>
```

attributeSubFeatureRemove.tag file

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<%@ attribute name="attribute" required="true" type="com.medtronic.b2b.core.dto.HCCB2BClassificationAttributeDTO" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="surgery" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/spine/surgery"%>               

    <c:forEach items="${attribute.subFeatures}" var="subAttribute">
        <c:forEach items="${subAttribute.attributeValues}" var="subValue">
           <c:if test="${ subValue.preSelectionRequired}">
             <c:set var="replaceParams" value=":${subAttribute.name}:${subValue.name}" />
             <c:set var="removeURL" value="${fn:replace(removeURL, replaceParams, '')}" />
          </c:if>
        </c:forEach> 
        <surgery:attributeSubFeatureRemove attribute="${subAttribute}" />
     </c:forEach>
```

Here I am giving Type Attribute to access Object in tag file. And it works fine.